# sorting by x-y-coordinaten

Tags: sorting, gnuplot

I want to plot results in gnuplot that all lie on a circle. For each value I have the corresponding x-y coordinates and a corresponding ID number (so 4 columns in total), but in an unsorted order. The rows are to be sorted in such a way that the direction of rotation is from -x => -y => +x => +y and end again at -x. So the center of the circle is at 0. How to implement this with "sort" (or alternatively with "awk"?) command (using Linux)?

At Theozh's suggestion, I will formulate my problem a little more precisely.
Imagine the dial of a clock with small dots as minute symbols. The position of the minute points can be determined by polar coordinates or by Cartesian coordinates. My file contains the Cartesian coordinates with an associated value (result). The file contains 60 lines with x - y coordinates and the result in the third column. Depending on the quadrant, the signs of x and y change, of course. Unfortunately, the lines are NOT sorted in such a way that they correspond to the sense of circulation. So the line for the point "minute 30" is not in line 30, but e.g. in line 17. The task is to sort the lines by the coordinates so that they appear in the order from 1 to 60. In the diagram, the x-axis would then simply be defined from 1 to 60 and the y-axis would then contain the results (from the 3rd column)

My unsorted file (coordinates for a unit circle, result values simplified for a better overview)
[image]

And this is what I want to have (8 rows (every 45°) sorted counterclockwise):
[image]

Comment: What do you actually want to plot? Points with labels or points connected with lines with labels? In the first case the order doesn't matter, in the latter case the order is important. So, I assume the latter. With "-x => -y => +x => +y and end again at -x" you basically mean: counterclockwise starting from 9 o'clock (or 180°), correct? Can you please provide some minimal example data and code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear wording of my question. It is about the fact that in my result file the rows are not sorted in the circulation sense, but in random order. I now want to sort the lines so that they appear in sequence in or against the clockwise direction. I can only achieve this by using the x-y coordinates. In the end, the value is to be plotted over an angle.
So it is only about sorting the lines in a file correctly.

Comment: @Genschman thank you for the explanations. Please provide some realistic test data!

Comment: @Genschman thanks for the data, however, please keep in mind for potential next questions, please insert raw data always as text not as image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angle can be calculated directly from the x/y coordinates using the atan2() function.

You do not say exactly what it is that you want to plot.  If it is simply the points themselves (one point per line in the file), then this can be done easily inside gnuplot.  I show the output from gnuplot 5.5.  In earlier versions, and depending on exactly what you want to plot, it might require additional commands to sort the data in a separate step and then plot the sorted data.  If you clarify what exactly is supposed to go into the plot, I will modify the example accordingly.

Example using 100 points with random x and y coordinates:

```
set print $RANDOM
do for [i=1:100] { print rand(0)-0.5, rand(0)-0.5 }
unset print

set xrange [-1:1]
set yrange [-1:1]
set angle degrees
set cbrange [-180:180]; set cblabel "Angle"

set style data linespoints
plot $RANDOM using 1:2:(atan2($2,$1)):(atan2($2,$1)) smooth zsort lc palette
```

[image]

**Updated answer**

Revised to show a plot of the sample data as given

```
$DATA << EOD
X       Y       Result
-0.707  -0.707  222
-0.707   0.707  888
 0.707  -0.707  444
-1      0       111
 1      0       555
0.707   0.707   666
 0      1       777
 0      -1      333
EOD

set datafile columnheader       # allow for the line of labels
unset key

# atan2() returns a number between -pi and pi;   convert this to 0 -> 1
# You could make it run from 0->60 if you know in advance
# there will be 60 evenly spaced points
xcoord(a) = (a + pi) / (2 * pi)

plot $DATA using (xcoord(atan2($2,$1))):3:(atan2($2,$1)) smooth zsort with points
```

And actually, if you don't care what order the points are drawn in, only where they end up, the command is even simpler because there is no need to sort!

```
plot $DATA using (xcoord(atan2($2,$1))):3 with points
```

[image]

Comment: @ Ethan: thank you for your answer, but my real problem is much more simple: the lines in my data file are mixed up and need to be re-sorted. I would like to solve this (if at all possible) with "sort". But "sort" has to take into account 2 columns, in which also the signs for x and y change (depending on the quadrant).  So it is more a sort problem, than one of gnuplot. I think the solution would have to start somehow like this:
plot '< sort -k2,3 My_corrupt_datafile' w l .....

(Sorry, but my home language is unfortunately not English and I have to use a translator...)

Comment: That is exactly what the atan2(x,y) function is doing.   This function is not special to gnuplot; it should be available to you in just about any language or math library.   But so far as I know you cannot do this using purely the "sort" utility, you need a tool that can combine information from the two input columns.  I provided a gnuplot answer because you tagged the question as "gnuplot". You could modify the gnuplot script to write out a new, sorted, file rather than plotting it.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @Ethan, omg, I haven't noticed this `atan2` function (actually it is `atan2(y,x)` for whatever reason) but it has been there since "ever". So far, I calculated the angle "by hand" via `Angle(dx,dy) = (d=sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2), d==0 ? NaN : dy/d >= 0 ? acos(dx/d) : -acos(dx/d) )`.

Comment: @Ethan: You are absolutely right when you write " ... you need a tool that can combine information from the two input columns ". I was hoping that this could somehow be managed with "sort". But it seems to be a bit more complicated. I will look around for a tool, maybe awk, sed or similar. Nevertheless, thanks for the interest in my question.

Comment: @Genschman very likely it can all be done in gnuplot. Please edit your question and describe exactly what you want to plot (or make a hand-sketch) and give some example data.

Comment: @ Ethan: Thanks, a nice (mathematical) solution (the update one). But I must admit to my own shame that I understood atan2 only after I looked it up in Wikipedia.